# cordova-plugin-google-conversion plugin not work in the iOS (ionic framework)

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Got question about [cordova-plugin-google-conversion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-google-conversion) plugin not work in the iOS.
I implemented the code in the click event listener in controller like this

```
var currentPlatform = ionic.Platform.platform();
if (currentPlatform == 'ios')
{
    GappTrack.track("TRACKING-ID", "LABEL-ID", price, true);
}
```

And I have exact same code for android, the code works fine in Android but not in iOS.

What's the catch on iOS...?

If information I provided is too less, let me know.

Thanks everyone.